# Just audio: How to avoid skipped samples at first playback on Android?

Tags: flutter, just-audio

The app loads a few short (4-5 Seconds long) audio files during startup and plays them at certain events. It's basically working, except for one little detail on **Android**:

The first time an audio file is played, it sounds as if playback starts a few seconds into the file, instead of at the beginning. Any following attempts to play the file work as expected. It's just the very first playback that starts a little too late into the file.

Question now is, how can it be fixed?

This is how the files are loaded during initialization of the app:

```
  late AudioPlayer _someAudio;

  init() async {
     AudioLoadConfiguration loadCfg = AudioLoadConfiguration(
      androidLoadControl: AndroidLoadControl(
        prioritizeTimeOverSizeThresholds: true,
        minBufferDuration: const Duration(seconds: 10),
        maxBufferDuration: const Duration(seconds: 20),
        bufferForPlaybackDuration: const Duration(seconds: 10),
      ),
    );

    _someAudio = AudioPlayer(audioLoadConfiguration: loadCfg);
    await _someAudio.setAsset('assets/audio/someeffect.mp3');
  }
```

Note 1: `AudioLoadConfiguration` doesn't seem to have any effect here. It has just been added in an attempt to fix the issue.

And this is how the files are played:

```
  void playSomeEffect() async {
    await _someAudio.seek(Duration.zero);
    await _someAudio.play();
  }
```

Note 2: It seems to be an Android issue (iOS is working as expected). Happens on a Samsung and a Motorola - other devices have not yet been tested.

Do you have any ideas how to ensure that first playback starts at the beginning? Any advise is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I have heard of cases where a fraction of a second is skipped (because Android fades in the audio channel when it hasn't been used in a while), but not a "few seconds". You may consider reporting it as a bug.

Comment: @RyanHeise Thank you for the advise! Whats strange is that it happens with every audio clip when its played for the first time - so this seems to be a different issue. I will create a quick example and file a bug during the holidays. Thinking of it: Could this perhaps be an issue of the mp3 data? Lets see, maybe using wav file format behaves differently...

Answer (score 0):

I had audio file 90ms length, and this problem was very irritating.
I found that it occurs only one time for each **AudioPlayer** class.
After first play, It plays normally.

Here is the solution.

```
  // before your playing !
  Future<void> _initPlayers() async {
    await _yourAudioPlayer.setAsset('assets/empty.wav');
    await _yourAudioPlayer.load();
    await _yourAudioPlayer.play();
    await _yourAudioPlayer.stop();
    // do for your every player.
  }
```

Downlaod empty.wav file from any website, and play empty wav file first for every each before your players get into the action.
stop() is needed for discontinuing empty source.

This is simple and worked perfectly for me.